# Int values are not equal when values are over 150?

Tags: java, autoboxing

Code looks like

```
public void option() {
    seeTasks = tasks.getTasks();
        for (int i = 0; i < seeTasks.size(); i++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < seeBoxes.size(); b++) {
               System.out.println("see Tasks: " + seeTasks.get(i) + 
                           " see Boxes " + seeBoxes.get(b));
            if(seeTasks.get(i) == seeBoxes.get(b)) {
                option.add(seeTasks.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(option);
}
```

The `if` statement with `seeTaks.get(i)` wont go go through if the values of `seeTasks.get(i)`  is lower than 150. How can this be? As seen below, 370 doesnt get included. If I change 110 to 150, it wont go through.

Output of `println`'s is:

```
see Tasks: 50 see Boxes 50
see Tasks: 50 see Boxes 110
see Tasks: 50 see Boxes 150
see Tasks: 50 see Boxes 210
see Tasks: 50 see Boxes 270
see Tasks: 50 see Boxes 310
see Tasks: 50 see Boxes 370
see Tasks: 50 see Boxes 430
see Tasks: 110 see Boxes 50 
see Tasks: 110 see Boxes 110
see Tasks: 110 see Boxes 150
see Tasks: 110 see Boxes 210
see Tasks: 110 see Boxes 270
see Tasks: 110 see Boxes 310
see Tasks: 110 see Boxes 370
see Tasks: 110 see Boxes 430
see Tasks: 370 see Boxes 50
see Tasks: 370 see Boxes 110
see Tasks: 370 see Boxes 150
see Tasks: 370 see Boxes 210
see Tasks: 370 see Boxes 270
see Tasks: 370 see Boxes 310
see Tasks: 370 see Boxes 370
see Tasks: 370 see Boxes 430
[50, 110]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect

```
seeTasks.get(i)
```

and

```
seeBoxes.get(b)
```

both return an `Integer`. Then for values below 128, the `Integer` cache returns the same instance, but for larger values, new instances. Use `equals()`.

Comment: as an extra comment to this, this will happen for string literals too as the JVM caches these too.

Comment: Thanks! I really tried google, and even tried .isEqual as if it was a String. I had no idea. Thanks alot, it worked! :)

Comment: @NicePro Yes, the `Integer` cache is a trap that's easy to fall into.

Comment: Interesting!  I always thought `Integer` would unbox to `int` before the `==` comparison.  Nice answer!

Comment: @Jeff Not when both operands are `Integer`s. If you compare an `int` to an `Integer` with `==`, the `Integer` will be unboxed.

Comment: @Jeff The code would compile prior to Java 1.5, so it couldn't suddenly do something more sensible (might actually NPE) when autounboxing came along.

Comment: Some days ago I've written a Netbeans custom hint that searches for Integer comparison, because if you change int to Integer Netbeans doesn't warn you. Some suggestion can be foud here: http://www.alfplus.com/2013/02/netbeans-hint-for-boxing-type-comparison/